# How to categorize by color in Ruby like Dribbble?

Tags: ruby, image-processing

Dribble has a great feature that lets you browse shots by similar colors:
[image: Note the color droplets on the right side of the image]

What is the easiest way to generate something like this in Ruby?  Are there libraries or services that can manage this kind of processing?  I currently have 26k images which I'll need to process and I'm evaluating the best way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely rely on the `imagemagick` utility in some capacity. A quick search of available libraries turned up the Miro gem available here: https://github.com/jonbuda/miro.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which aspect of the problem you need help with - generating the swatches of colour or sorting by similar colours. Anyway, here is how you can use ImageMagick to generate the 6 best colours to represent an image and make that into a colour swatch of a resonable size:

```
convert input.png -colors 6 -unique-colors -scale 5000% swatch.png
```

[image]

If you want the colours as RGB triplets, just change the command to this:

```
convert input.png -colors 6 -unique-colors +matte -colorspace RGB  txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 6,1,255,rgb
0,0: (1623,1472,1531)  #060606  rgb(6,6,6)
1,0: (10693,4106,4231)  #2A1010  rgb(42,16,16)
2,0: (23082,8867,9471)  #5A2325  rgb(90,35,37)
3,0: (8667,28247,37488)  #226E92  rgb(34,110,146)
4,0: (40714,34524,37545)  #9E8692  rgb(158,134,146)
5,0: (59611,58620,58816)  #E8E4E5  rgb(232,228,229)
```

And if you want to find the *distance* between two colours, e.g. the first and last colours listed above, you can use this:

```
compare -metric RMSE xc:"rgb(232,228,229)" xc:"rgb(6,6,6)" null:
57484 (0.87715)
```

The number in parentheses means that the colour distance in the RGB colour cube is 87% of the distance between black and white - i.e. normalised to the diagonal of the colour cube as 100%. As the first number is nearly black, i.e. rgb(0,0,0) and the second is nearly white, i.e. rgb(255,255,255), the distance between the colours is 87%.

There are Ruby bindings for ImageMagick - [here](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org) and [here](http://magickwand.rubyforge.org).